# Python 3.3.2 on Windows - MysqlDB & pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, mysql-python

I'm on Windows 8 using Python 3.3.2 , trying to connect to mysql online via ssh(putty) already running

I tried installing mysqldb using

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

but i get this [**LOG**](http://pastebin.com/FfggM4bM)

When I try to connect using pymyqslafter after installation with this code

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='bitnami', passwd=None, db='extractor')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM eaexpress")
for response in cur:
    print(response)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 780, in _connect
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\python.py", line 19, in <module>
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='bitnami', passwd=None, db='extractor')

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 634, in __init__
    self._connect()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 818, in _connect
    2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ('module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX')")
 >>>
```

I'm connected to myphpadmin via ssh , it does load well on browser. Unless there is a way for python to connect using openssh or ppk file without the need of ssh, that would be even better but before that. I would have to fix these issue in connection.

Any advice in connecting to mysql on my server?

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that you are running the code on your Windows box, and trying to connect to `localhost` (i.e., your Windows machine itself). When you connect to the linux box with Putty, you are on the remote machine, and `localhost` is *that* computer. You should be doing all the installation of scripts on the Linux box, or else make sure that the remote database is able to accept connections from your Windows machine without Putty. You need to make sure your Mysqldb installation is rock solid too - no use trying to troubleshoot the connection if the library doesn't work.

Comment: then the lib really suck then. I'm setting up Restful. There isnt much support for this. Python ... oh well... And i need it running on windows hmmm ....

Comment: If you decide to try MySQL again, you should try `pip install pymysql` and see if that works any better. Supposed to be easier than `mysqldb` [Short description](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the huge list of **Unofficial Windows Binaries** for *Python Extension Packages* which are extremely useful for Windows users.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Go to the link and search for **MySQL-python** and install it and you are good to go.

Cheers !

Comment: Does it matter what version mysql on the server i'm trying to connect to. Mysql is running my my linux on a server hosted at amazon but i'm trying to connect to it from my windows python code.

Comment: Ammm, it doesnt matter thpugh.